# What's the best way to report SPAM user accounts?

Tags: support, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple way to report spammy users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36131/simple-way-to-report-spammy-users)

A question i asked got a reply from a spam user account.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1328168/air-jordan-shoes

what's the best way to report these findings?

Answer (score 12):

### Flag the answer as spam.

**Step one:**

[image: Click the "flag" link below the offending answer]

**Step two:**

[image: Select the "it is spam" flag reason, then click the "Flag Answer" button]

**Step three:**

There is no step three.

---

Note that if you happen across an account that has posted *multiple* spam answers, it's not necessary to painstakingly flag *each* of their answers as spam. Rather, flag one of their answers, then select the "other" option under "it needs moderator attention" and explain in the textbox provided what the problem is. The moderator who processes your flag will blow away the entire account, taking all of the the offending answers with it.

Comment: My instinct made me try to downvote the screenshot after reading it. :P

Comment: I know how to flag a -post- .. i ment to flag a -USER-

Comment: @Pure: You can't flag a user. You can, however, flag a post made by a user.

Comment: I disagree with the flag. A Mod-flag explaining that the whole account can be purged might be better suited...if the name of the account is not a dead give-away, that is...

Comment: @Bobby Yes, a mod flag would be equally helpful. No, it doesn't really matter, spam flags are a bit special, a single one is powerless but a few of them have super awesome powers. If it's spam, use the spam flag, it's essentially the same as writing "this is spam, purge this sucker" in a custom flag.

Comment: This isn't helpful if the spam is a comment, not an answer.  There's no way to flag a comment as spam that I see.  (In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937358/android-ndk-how-do-you-redirect-syslog-output-to-logcat/10937571#10937571, the spam was first posted as answer that was flagged and deleted.  Then the same thing showed up as a comment.)