# Inactive user accounts which appear to have only been created to advertise a product/service?

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-detection

Recently, I was typing in some *spam keywords* into the user search and found some suspicious users that meet the following characteristics :

- username contains one of the same keywords that often shows up in spam posts
- no activity except for editing their about me section
- their about me section contains an advertisement for a product/service that is ***very unrelated*** to programming *or the topic of the site they're on*, as well as a link or two to view/purchase the product/service
- last seen date is usually the same day they created their account

<sup>*As to not advertise their spam, I won't link to any examples of this here.*</sup>

In my opinion, these accounts I've found appear to have only been created to spam. Maybe they were intended to post spam as a question, but for some reason never did. Or maybe they just sit there hoping for people to inadvertently run across them while sliding beneath the community's radar. Or I guess maybe they did post some spam, that was deleted, but a mod never nuked their account.

Is this considered an act of spam to SE? Or does SE only consider it spam when it's posted as a question/answer/comment/chat message? Is there anything SE would like us to do in the case we find an account like this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84113/266359, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36131/266359

Comment: Some of these probably did once ask/answer but it got deleted without the account getting destroyed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Spam should be removed. Jeff says [don't hesitate to email us if you find these, and we'll fix ASAP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry#comment321224_105228).

I searched and observed that most of these users have more than one account across the network, [which prevents auto-removal of their accounts as an abandoned account.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)

[From Jeff's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105228/245167):

> Note that
>
> Links in your "about me" field don't work for low-rep users; we don't
> allow more than 2 links by new users in this field, and they aren't
> actually hyperlinked until you have 15 rep.
>
> The "website" field is not hyperlinked until you generate 15 rep.
>
> ... so the damage potential here is small.
>
> **That said of course we hate spammers and I love killing their user
> accounts, but there is a weird little edge condition of users who set
> up accounts with spam profile info but never ask or answer questions.**

(emphasis mine)